# why didn't show my Buttons with image. it only shows image whats error in it?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()
root.title("Image Viewer App")

img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("../images/1.jpg"))
img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("../images/2.jpg"))
img3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("../images/3.jpg"))
img4 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("../images/4.jpg"))
img5 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("../images/5.jpg"))
img6 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("../images/6.jpg"))
img7 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("../images/7.jpg"))
img8 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("../images/8.jpg"))
img9 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("../images/9.jpg"))
img10 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("../images/10.jpg"))
img11 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("../images/11.jpg"))
img12 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("../images/12.jpg"))
img13 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("../images/samantha.jpg"))
image_list = [img1, img2, img3, img4, img4, img5, img6, img7, img8, img9, img10, img11,img12, img13]

def forward(image_number):
    global my_label
    global btn_back
    global btn_forward

    my_label.grid_forget()
    my_label = Label(image=image_list[image_number-1])
    btn_back = Button(root, text="<<", command=lambda: backward(image_number-1))
    btn_forward = Button(root, text=">>", command=lambda: forward(image_number+1))
    if image_number == 13:
        btn_forward = Button(root, text=">>", state=DISABLED)
    my_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)
    btn_back.grid(row=1, column=0)
    btn_forward.grid(row=1, column=2)

def backward(image_number):
    global my_label
    global btn_back
    global btn_forward
    my_label.grid_forget()
    my_label = Label(image=image_list[image_number - 1])
    btn_back = Button(root, text="<<", command=lambda: backward(image_number - 1))
    btn_forward = Button(root, text=">>", command=lambda: forward(image_number + 1))

    my_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)
    btn_back.grid(row=1, column=0)
    btn_forward.grid(row=1, column=2)

my_label = Label(root, image=img1)
my_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)
btn_back = Button(root, text="<<", command=backward)
btn_exit = Button(root, text="Exit", command=root.quit)
btn_forward = Button(root, text=">>", command=lambda: forward(2))

btn_back.grid(row=1, column=0)
btn_exit.grid(row=1, column=1)
btn_forward.grid(row=1, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please add more details regarding your error - not only code

Answer (score 0):

You simply use a global variable.
1) Remove lambda and just put *function name*
2) Further you can add other if/else arg.

```
image_list = [img1, img2, img3, img4, img4, img5, img6, img7, img8, img9, img10, 
              img11, img12, img13]
img_index = 0


def forword():
    global img_index
    img_index += 1          # THis will help to move img_index by 1

    label = Label(root, image=image_list[img_index])     # with  'image_list[img_index]'  you will get img. name on that index
    label.grid()

def backward():
    global img_index
    img_index -= 1

    label = Label(root, image=image_list[img_index])
    label.grid()
```

Comment: It will get more and more images shown since the previous one is not removed when either the forward and backward button is clicked.  Create the label once and update its image instead.

Comment: But it didn't also show buttons. that was the problem actually